# Why doesn't my element update during the else part but during the if part?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a program where it has a collection of calculators, and for some reason when I try to change the innerhtml of a certain text it only changes it during the if statement and not during the else part.

```
function Palindrome() {
//Fix not changing to processing when doing new palindrome.
var Division = 0;
var input = document.getElementById("PalindromeInput").value;
var GiveAnswer = document.getElementById("PalindromeAnswer");
var Answer = String(input);

while (0 < 1) {
    if (Answer == Answer.split("").reverse().join("")) {
        GiveAnswer.innerHTML = `That is a palindrome of the ${Division}th Division.`;
        break
    } else {
        GiveAnswer.innerHTML = `Processing...`;
        Division = Division + 1;
        Answer = String(parseInt(String(Answer)) + parseInt(Answer.split("").reverse().join("")));
        };
};
```

};

https://replit.com/@ButterDoesFly/Arcane-Calculators#index.html

Comment: I stuck your code in a snippet and it works.. somewhat. I don't understand what the ELSE portion of the IF is meant to do  create a palindrome and put it in the text box or in the innerHTML?

Comment: `while (0 < 1)` - You have an infinite loop?  The `else` doesn't break the loop in any way.  When you step through this in a debugger, what causes the loop to ever finish when you're invoking the `else` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function Palindrome() {
    //Fix not changing to processing when doing new palindrome.
    var Division = 0;
    var input = document.getElementById("PalindromeInput").value;
    var GiveAnswer = document.getElementById("PalindromeAnswer");
    var Answer = String(input);

  GiveAnswer.innerHTML = `Processing...`;
  setTimeout(()=>{
    while (0 < 1) {
        if (Answer == Answer.split("").reverse().join("")) {
            GiveAnswer.innerHTML = `That is a palindrome of the ${Division}th Division.`;
            break
        } else {
      Division = Division + 1;
            Answer = String(parseInt(String(Answer)) + parseInt(Answer.split("").reverse().join("")));
            };
    };
  },1000)
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p id="PalindromeAnswer">This will tell you the number its at and then the answer.</p>
  <input type="text" id="PalindromeInput" placeholder="What number would you like to enter?">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="Palindrome()" value="Submit" id="PalindromeButton">
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <!--
  This script places a badge on your repl's full-browser view back to your repl's cover
  page. Try various colors for the theme: dark, light, red, orange, yellow, lime, green,
  teal, blue, blurple, magenta, pink!
  -->
  <script src="https://replit.com/public/js/replit-badge.js" theme="blue" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

result is rendering very fast such that changes are not reflecting in ui..add a timeout so that changes reflect in front end

Comment: Oh I get it that makes sense, but just to verify I'm understanding this because of the timeout we're stopping it before it goes through making it delayed but also allowing the process text to go through correct?

Comment: Yes by giving a timeout of 1 sec,  changes done to text element will be reflected before running logic.. Else we can see only the final text given after the completion of loop

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I guess the reason for this is that the function never goes to the `else` part because it gets `break` every time. Remember that `.reverse()` reverses the array in place so the `if` statement will always be true. Try to add different variable for the reversed answer.